# PySpark - how do I take the upper triangle of a distrance matrix in a data frame?

Tags: python, pyspark

I've got a distance matrix in a PySpark data frame, and I'm attempting to take the upper (or lower) triangle of the data and have the results in another data frame.

For example, I'm trying to transform this:

> 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> 2, 1, 2, 3
>
> 3, 2, 1, 2
>
> 4, 3, 2, 1

Into this:

> 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> 0, 1, 2, 3
>
> 0, 0, 1, 2
>
> 0, 0, 0, 1

I've looked into numpy, but from what I've read that would break the concurrent benefit of Spark.

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe isn't a matrix. They are both collections of rows, but a dataframe doesn't have a strict ordering of those rows.

If you have a column in your dataframe which indicates the `row_num` of that row then you could apply a `map` function to set all columns with `index < row_num` to zero.

[There are matrix types in Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-data-types.html#distributed-matrix), and if you use those you'll have access to row and column indices. This datatype can be used something like a tuple of a `((x, y), Value)`, with coordinates pointing to values. You would then simply set a value to zero when `y > x`.

---

You say you have looked into numpy but it would break the concurrent benefit of Spark. I assume you mean the distributed, parallel nature of Spark? If your data is small enough to fit on a single machine, i.e. doesn't need to be distributed, then you'll certainly get better performance from numpy. Would highly recommend looking into it in depth.